# Hydrogen and Helium ideal gas behavior in room temperature

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, gas-laws

Which one of hydrogen and helium behaves more like ideal gas **in room temperature**...

I thought hydrogen gas would show more ideal behavior in room temperature because it has lighter mass (less no of electron) although it's diatomic, so there would be less attraction.
However, I saw one question on the book and they said that the helium gas is more likely to show the ideal gas behavior in room temperature, not the hydrogen gas..

So, can someone please give me an idea how my thinking is wrong?.

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inert gas molecules, intermolecular interactions would be by Van der Waals forces, which are based on the total volume and polarizability of the gas molecule.

The diatomic hydrogen is larger and more polarizable of the two.

Answer (score 0):

He is more nearer to ideal behaviour than hydrogen because ideal behaviour also depends on the charge spread over area or size of molecule. So the charge density of hydrogen is expanded increases the size of hydrogen due to which interactions between hydrogen molecules increases and hence show less ideal character as compared to helium and helium charge density is bound to single nucleus. Therefore the low charge density of hydrogen show little

Comment: You do not complete the last sentence. Please check and edit.